# Decision upon whether to Drop or Impute the missing Data

Tags: r, python, stata

I have panel data having 26 countries and each country has of 22 years data (i.e. 572 Cases or records). There are total 8 attributes (1 dependent and 7 independent ). When i analyzed missing values per record wise (listwise) i got maximum of 19 % of missing data per record (case). But when i analyzed the missing values per country wise across all the variables then i got maximum 53% of missing data in one XYZ country. I have also analyzed that which country has how much missing data per attribute wise and I got that one country other than XYZ has 95 % of missing data in one attribute and 100 % data available in rest of the attribute. It is also the pre requisite to deal with panel data that it should be balance with respect to country wise and year wise to avoid biasness.

I have also applied MCAR (Missing Completely at Random) algorithm which also says that that randomness is significant.

My question is that which country i should drop and which country i should keep ? Whether i have go towards any imputation technique or just drop those all countries which have even single value missing? How would i take decision upon that so that my model fitness could not be effected as well? 
Looking for strong argument. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data?

Comment: @JaredS may i put here the screenshot of that data?